Формы глаголов на ТЕ (идемте, пойдемте и другие)
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА СЕ

Вот примеры предложений:

Идёмте наверх, я покажу вам в зимнем саду новых золотых рыбок в аквариуме.
Александр Беляев, Властелин мира, 1926
Пойдёмте домой! — предложил Климков. Горький Максим, Жизнь ненужного человека, 1907

Какой вариант более корректен по грамматике и стилю и почему они образуются от разных глаголов идти и пойти.

Какая разница между выражениями пойдемте домой  и давайте пойдем домой? В современном языке используются обе формы?

Есть еще форма форма пошлите, почему она считается просторечной?


Какое лицо и число у этих форм глагола? Давай и давайте, пойдем и пойдемте — обе формы множественного числа?

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА СЕ
ФОРМЫ ГЛАГОЛОВ НА ТЕ (повелительное наклонение)

КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО ГОВОРИТЬ?

Идем, пойдем, пойдемте, давай пойдем — нейтральные формы. Пошли — разговорная форма. Пошлите — ненормативно.
 № 277956
Здравствуйте, как правильно говорить: идем, пошли или 
пойдемте в побудительном предложении? В офисе используют все 
варианты...
ОТВЕТ. Стилистически нейтральный, грамотный вариант – 
пойдем, пойдемте, идем. Пошли – разговорный вариант, 
впрочем, в непринужденной устной речи употребление слова 
пошли ошибочным не является. А вот форма пошлите однозначно 
неправильная.


А ЧТО ЭТО ЗА ФОРМЫ?

Все эти формы имеют значение повелительного наклонения, но при этом к формам повелительного наклонения относятся пойдемте (синтетическая) и  давай пойдем (аналитическая, составная), выражающие совместность действия.
Формы идем, пойдем, пошли относятся к изъявительному наклонению: (мы) идем, (мы) пойдем, (мы) пошли, но в переносном значении выражают повелительное наклонение. Это надо указывать при морфологическом разборе слов.
А вот пошлите — некорректная форма (это повел. наклонение для глагола послать; кроме того, здесь аналитическая форма глагола пойти на ТЕ образована неверно.

КАК ВЫБРАТЬ ФОРМУ ДЛЯ КОНКРЕТНОГО ГЛАГОЛА

До недавнего времени формы на ТЕ были довольно распространенными, но в современном языке аналитическая форма с частицами давай/давайте активно вытесняет эти формы, сравнить: Пойдёмте, Семен Семеныч, — продолжала Елена Ивановна, обращаясь исключительно ко мне, — посмотримте лучше обезьян (Ф. Достоевский). Будемте говорить прямо и откровенно (А. Куприн).
Формы на ТЕ в основном равноправны для глаголов однонаправленного действия вида идти, пойти, а раньше выбор зависел от вида глагола. Глаголы НВ имели только аналитическую форму, в отличие от глаголов СВ, сравним: давайте дружить, давайте спать, но споемте, друзья.
Ответы Справочной службы 1 и 2
ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ
1. Основные сведения
Литневская
Повелительное наклонение (императив) выражает побуждение к действию в форме просьбы или приказа. Глагол в повелительном наклонении не изменяется по временам.
 Повелительное наклонение имеет следующие **средства 
 выражения**: в 1 лице представлена так называемая форма 
 совместного действия (пойд-ем-те, давайте пойдём), в форме 
 2 лица повелительное наклонение выражается формообразующими 
 суффиксами -и— (пиш-и—ø) или -Ø— (сядь—Ø-ø), в 3 лице 
 представлены составные формы с вспомогательными элементами 
 пусть, пускай, да (пусть идёт / идут, да здравствует).

Таблица

Морфологический разбор

Разбор спрягаемых форм глагола производится по такой схеме:
  1. Глагол. Начальная форма.
  2. Морфологические признаки:
  а) постоянные:
  — переходность,
  — возвратность,
  — вид,
  — спряжение,
  б) непостоянные:
  — наклонение (изъявительное, условное, повелительное),
  — время (в изъявительном наклонении),
  — лицо (в наст. / буд. времени изъявительного наклонения и 
  в повелительном наклонении),
  — род (в ед. числе прошедшего времени изъявительного 
  наклонения и условного наклонения),
  — число.
  3. Синтаксическая роль в предложении


При определении наклонения надо иметь в виду то, что мы характеризуем форму глагола, поэтому в том случае, когда форма наклонения употреблена переносно (изъявительное в значении условного и др.), надо характеризовать форму глагола, а не его значение. Так, в предложении Сходил бы ты за газетами условное наклонение употреблено в значении повелительного, однако при разборе указывается, что глагол стоит в форме условного наклонения.

Примеры разбора (у Литневской)


пусть знает — глаг., начальн. форма знать;
постоянные признаки: перех., невозвр., НСВ, I спр.;
непостоянные признаки: в повелит. накл., 3 лице, ед. числе;
синтаксическая роль: сказуемое.
подождите — глаг., начальн. форма подождать;
постоянные признаки: перех., невозвр., СВ, I спр.;
непостоянные признаки: в повел. накл., 2 лице, мн. числе;
синтаксическая роль: сказуемое.
Морфологический разбор «давай пойдём»
В этом случае разбираются отдельно формы глагола давать и пойти.
Морфологический разбор глагола пойдемте

Вопрос с сайта Рунглиш СЕ (в переводе)
Что именно происходит с несколькими глаголами, имеющими императивное спряжением -мте?
Есть некоторые русские глаголы, у которых императивное 
спряжение заканчивается на -мте, например идёмте. Но что 
именно здесь происходит? Мне кажется, что это смесь 
повелительного наклонения первого лица множественного числа 
и повелительного наклонения второго лица множественного 
числа (например, "ребята, поехали").

Я видел, что это называется просто императивным спряжением 
от первого лица множественного числа (ср. идёмте в 
Викисловаре), но я не думаю, что это имеет смысл, потому что 
оно не будет использоваться при разговоре с кем-то, к кому 
вы обращаетесь как ты.

Ответ на вопрос не показался мне однозначно правильным. Поэтому я предлагаю  разобраться в теме, используя приведенные ниже материалы.
Конспект статьи  А. А. Дуденкова
ФУНКЦИОНИРОВАНИЕ ФОРМ ИМПЕРАТИВА НА -МТЕ В РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ
В статье указано значение форм на -МТЕ, способ образования, история появления форм в русском языке и их современное состояние.
Введение. В данной работе будут представлены результаты первого этапа корпусного исследования современных русских императивных "совместных" форм, а именно функционирования так называемой формы множественного числа совместного действия.
Совместная форма или, как менее точно ее называют, форма 1-го лица императива, является одной из наиболее специализированных форм выражения волеизъявления, направленного не только на собеседника, но и на говорящего.
Общая семантика. При помощи совместной формы говорящий побуждает собеседника или нескольких собеседников принять участие в действии, которое он сам намеревается произвести (пойдем, идемте).  Здесь множество исполнителей действия  включает говорящего и, соответственно, получается на единицу больше
Если бы не существовало форм множественного числа, то формы будущего времени типа идем можно было бы считать не императивом, а особым типом употребления индикатива (изъявит. наклонения). Поэтому ключевым для выделения этого типа императива становится существование формы на -мте, образование которой оказалось возможным благодаря особым свойствам сегмента -те.
Агглютинативность -те.  Это свойство присоединяться (приклеиваться) В русском языке формы повелительного наклонения множественного числа отличаются от прочих глагольных форм агглютинацией окончаний. Именно этим  характером соединения морфем в повелительном наклонении и объясняется относительная легкость, с которой его окончания добавляются к глагольным формам изъявительного наклонения, порождая исследуемые здесь формы типа пойдемте (и даже изолированную форму пошлите образованную от прошедшего времени глагола пойти), либо образуют императивные по семантике формы от других частей речи (полноте, нате).
Исходя из того, что императивные формы образуются агглютинативно, формы типа пойдемте, возьмемте имеют два соединившихся окончания - 1 и 2 лица мн. ч. (-м и -те) и тем самым представляют собой явление, необычное в рамках всей грамматической системы индоевропейских языков.
Образование форм императива совместного действия. В русском языке различаются синтетические и аналитические формы императива совместного действия. Синтетические формы образуются от глаголов совершенного вида (посмотрим / посмотримте, но не *смотрим / смотримте). Единственным исключением из этого правила является небольшой закрытый класс глаголов, образующих синтетическую форму несовершенного вида (бежимте, будемте).
Аналитические формы являются периферийными и образуются от глаголов обоих видов (давай посмотрим, давайте смотреть, и др.). У глаголов несовершенного вида аналитические формы являются единственным типом форм императива совместного действия. В качестве вспомогательных слов выступают слова будем / будемте и давай / давайте, сочетающиеся с инфинитивом несовершенного вида.
Сравнительно-историческая характеристика формы совместного действия.
Конечное -мте в форме повелительного наклонения 1-го лица множественного числа появилось в русском языке сравнительно недавно. Это сочетание впервые засвидетельствовано со значением побуждения в песне XVII века в форме грянемте [Кузьмина 1951: 134].
Употребляемость форм на -мте в русском языке. В результате исследования текстов НКРЯ мы сделали вывод о том, что наиболее свободно эти формы использовались во второй половине 19 века, что же касается актуального момента развития русского языка, то регулярно используется лишь несколько словоформ от конкретных глаголов. См. график, построенный с помощью сервиса НКРЯ, на котором ясно виден пик 1848-1868 годов и постепенное уменьшение популярности формы (второй пик графика приходится на 1956 год).
Формы на -мте в 19 веке. Исходя из графика, пиком употребляемости для исследуемой формы является третья четверть 19 века. Данная форма быстро вошла в оборот и закрепилась как в художественной, так и разговорной речи. В этот период замечается наибольшее число образований формы от разных глаголов и, как следствие, увеличение количества форм единичного употребления. Наиболее часто в 19 веке используются несколько словоформ с семантикой передвижения (пойдемте - 1708 3, поедемте - 233), однако наблюдаются и другие словоформы (будемте - 93, сядемте - 51, едемте - 47). Форма употреблялась неограниченно, образуя множество словоформ от различных глаголов. Это доказывает большое количество единичных словоформ (вооружимтесь, ответимте, отнимемте, побалакаемте, усядемтесь и др.).
Формы на -мте в настоящее время. В настоящее время функционирует всего несколько форм, образованных от глаголов со значением передвижения. Это глагольные формы пойдемте, пройдемте, идемте, поедемте. Сфера употребления этих форм сугубо бытовая. Примеров употребления других форм в текстах последнего десятилетия фактически нет.   Это доказывает, что в сознании современного говорящего данная форма маркирована как устаревшая.
Статья Пошли или пойдём?
В современном русском языке верными вариантами являются идём и пойдём. Это общеупотребительные глаголы, использование которых отвечает литературной норме: «– Но ведь это глупо! – Нет, идём! Я тебя зову… я требую тебя в фехтовальный зал!» (Н. Лесков).
В том случае, когда необходимо указать на совместность действия или подчеркнуть уважительное отношение к какой-либо персоне, к глаголам добавляют постфикс -те: идёмте, пойдёмте.  «Господа, идёмте садиться в экипажи… Уже пора!» (А. Чехов); «С моею музою своенравной / Пойдёмте слушать шум дубравный / Над безыменною рекой» (А. Пушкин).
Из Русской корпусной грамматики. Императив
Об использовании форм будущего времени (пойдем, пойдешь, давай пойдем) для выражения повелит. наклонения.
Императивное значение (значение побуждения к действию) всегда апеллирует к ситуации в будущем (побуждение к действию возможно только для еще не совершенных действий). Неудивительно, что в силу семантической близости показатели императива и будущего времени часто обнаруживают целый ряд общих свойств.
Целый ряд разного рода императивных употреблений возможен для форм будущего времени в русском языке, в том числе употребления в значении жесткого приказа или (под отрицанием) запрета (пойдешь со мной / никуда сегодня не пойдешь), инструкции (у магазина повернешь налево), разрешения (так и быть, пойдешь со мной), см. п.2.1.
Специализированная форма императива, формально никак не связанная с формой будущего времени, существует в русском языке только для 2-го лица (побуждение адресата к совершению им действия): читай, читайте. Формы будущего времени, не имеющие ограничений по лицу, оказываются естественным источником средств выражения императивных значений для невторого лица: Пойдем в кино! Давай пойдем в кино.
